# How do I get the value in the screenshot in python?

Tags: python, uv, uv-image-editor

How to get the values (in the screenshot) when i have the whole object selected in python? How do I get the value in the screenshot in python?
[image]

Answer (score 5):

This will get the values of every vert

```py
import bpy, bmesh
from bpy import context as C

me = C.active_object.data

# edit mode
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

# object mode
# bm = bmesh.new()
# bm.from_mesh(me)

uv_lay = bm.loops.layers.uv.active
for vert in bm.verts:
    for loop in vert.link_loops:
        uv = loop[uv_lay].uv
        print("Loop UV: %f, %f" % uv[:])
```

https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.html#customdata-access

Comment: I need to get the value of all vertices together, not each one separately, and so that they can be moved together.  Thanks for the answer, but it's not that

Comment: @tormozzzz: then you should edit and improve your question, because how should karan or anybody else know what you mean if you don't write it in your 2 sentence question!?

Comment: @chris - this is in the question(see screenshot)

Comment: Nope, it is not clear. You wrote : how do I get the value? You didn’t wrote: how do I get the values.

Comment: @Chris - value -> tuple(x,y), values -> x,y; Everyone can understand in their own way, but the meaning is the same )

Comment: This post answers the Blender part of the question, it shows how to access this information in Blender API. Converting it to a different form like saving all the data in a list is a matter of Python, not Blender... Though it looks like the answer is wrong, `bm` is never created? Some lines have been omitted?